# Assigning new values to a raster based on the mask layer in QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, polygon, rasterization

In QGIS, I have two layers: raster and vector (green colored) of the same area of interest. Now, I want to assign "1" to the pixels which lie within the green region, and for the rest assign 0. How can I handle that? Is that possible?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Rasterize the polygon layer: `Menu Raster / Conversion /Rasterize (Vector to Raster)`

Set `1` for `A fixed value to burn` and set `Assign a specified nodata value to output bands` to `Not set`. You get a new raster layer with pixels = 1 where the polygons are and 0 everywhere else. Use the desired extent for the new raster (e.g. select the extent and resolution of your existing raster). Be aware that all layers have the same CRS.

[image]

*Output: white=1, black=0*

[image]